UseQueryTable not finding the table on the webpage
I followed some tutorials on how to get tables into excel using VBA and ended up with this short piece of code:
Public Sub UseQueryTable()
Dim url As String
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/PRC_HICP_MIDX/default/table?lang=en&category=prc.prc_hicp"

Dim table As QueryTable
Set table = Sheet1.QueryTables.Add("URL;" & url, Sheet1.Range("A1"))

With table
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebTables = 1
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub

However when i  run it, i get a response that "web query returned no data"
Am i referencing the table wrong?
Why is it returning no data?

If you inspect the source code of the page you will see that there isn't any static table. So, you can't fetch the table data with this code. You may need to use Selenium.
